# Add varchar column to order address

Tags: database, installation, column

I am trying to add a few varchar fields to the sales/order_address table but am coming up against a column definition error.

I have the following code:

```
$oInstaller->getConnection()
    ->addColumn(
        $oInstaller->getTable('sales/order_address'),
        'address_email',
        array(
            'nullable' => false,
            'length' => 255,
            'type' => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR,
            'comment' => 'Company Email Address'
        )
    );
```

This returns the error: `[message:protected] => Invalid column definition data`

If I change the code to use `Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER` then the code runs and the column is added. I have tried removing the length and nullable attributes but to no avail.

**EDIT**

When updating the script is updated as follows then it works. Does anyone know what causes this error?

```
$oInstaller->getConnection()
    ->addColumn(
        $oInstaller->getTable('sales/order_address'),
        'address_email',
        Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_VARCHAR . '(255)'
    );
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `TYPE_TEXT`. `TYPE_VARCHAR` is deprecated (`@see Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::$_ddlColumnTypes`)

And don't worry about the storage space. If you specify type `TYPE_TEXT` but set `length` to lets say `255` Magento will create a MySQL column of `VARCHAR` type.

Comment: works ! `->addColumn('name', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, 255, array(
        'nullable'  => true,
        'length' => 255,
    ), null)`

Comment: I'm surprised that it was this simple... The class says it would internally convert the deprecated types to non-deprecated, but I suppose that's for pre-existing values? Either way, plus one