# How to add new column to existing module table?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, collection, upgrade, column

How can I add a new column to existing Magento core table via install script? (without using pure SQL)

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'custom_value', array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'length'    => 255,
    'after'     => null, // column name to insert new column after
    'comment'   => 'Title'
    ));   
$installer->endSetup();
```

and also I am updating version as per upgrade version 
I have created `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.0-0.1.1` in `sql` folder and added above code. and change version in `config.xml` and cleared caches too, 
but its not working.

Comment: @qaisar Satti ...its not updating my table what should in do can you suggest me

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/add-varchar-column-to-order-address?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Please use :

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()
->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'custom_value', array(
    'type'      => Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    'nullable'  => false,
    'length'    => 255,
    'after'     => null, // column name to insert new column after
    'comment'   => 'Title'
    ));   
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

might help you.

```
$installer = $this;

$installer -> startSetup();
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'),'custom_value', "varchar(255)  NOT NULL default '0'");


$installer -> endSetup();
```

Comment: i have used this ..still did not change