# Magento 2: Undefined variable: installer

Tags: magento2, php, database, magento2.2.3, installdata

I'm too new to `Magento`: i'm getting an error when `setup:upgrade`, here is my code:
**`app/code/Adamsmage/Checkoutattribute/Setup/InstallData.php`**

```
<?php
namespace Adamsmage\Checkoutattribute\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'example', [
            'label' => 'example',
            'input' => 'text',
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'position' => 333,
            'visible' => true,
            'system' => false,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);


        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'example')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address',
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'customer_address'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('quote_address'),
            'example',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255
            ]
        );

        $installer->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $installer->getTable('sales_order_address'),
            'example',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'length' => 255
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

**ERROR**:
[image]

Comment: Just replace $installer variable to $setup

Comment: already tried but getting this error: `Impossible to create a column without comment.`

Comment: add the comment to the column information   [
'type' => 'varchar',
'length' => 255,
'comment' =>'Example'
]

Comment: now getting this error: `Invalid column definition data`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $installer

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoShipment/blob/master/Setup/InstallData.php#L35-L36

See how I use `$salesSetup` to add column to `sales_order` tables

```
use Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory;
/**
 * InstallData class
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $salesSetupFactory;
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Setup\SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(SalesSetupFactory $salesSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->salesSetupFactory = $salesSetupFactory;
    }
```

```
        $salesSetup = $this->salesSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $salesSetup->addAttribute(
            'order',
            'prevent_automatic_shipment',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                'length' => 5,
                'default' => 2,
                'unsigned' => true,
                'nullable' => false,
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'grid' => false
            ]
        );
```

So you would need to define a variable for you `quote_address` and `sales_order_address` addColumn's

Answer (score 0):

Remember that

> Implementing declarative schema is not a requirement for Magento 2.3.
>   However, upgrade scripts will be phased out in favor of declarative
>   schema.

I will use data patch in your case. We need to create two separate scripts: data is for DML, schema is for DDL.

app/code/Vendor/CustomerDemo/Setup/Patch/Data/CustomerAddressAttribute.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomerDemo\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class CustomerAddressAttribute implements DataPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * @var CustomerSetupFactory
     */
    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * @var AttributeSetFactory
     */
    private $attributeSetFactory;

    /**
     * CustomerAgeAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     * @param CustomerSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        CustomerSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }


    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * @return DataPatchInterface|void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function apply()
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $eavSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType(Customer::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();
        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            'customer_address',
            'example',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Example',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 130,
                'visible' => true,
                'position'  => 130,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'system'  => false
            ]
        );

        $exampleAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'example');

        $exampleAttribute->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' =>
                [
                    'customer_address_edit',
                    'customer_register_address',
                    'adminhtml_customer_address',
                    'customer_address'
                ],
        ]);

        $exampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

app/code/Vendor/CustomerDemo/Setup/Patch/Schema/ExampleAttribute.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomerDemo\Setup\Patch\Schema;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\SchemaPatchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class ExampleAttribute implements SchemaPatchInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ModuleDataSetupInterface
     */
    private $moduleDataSetup;

    /**
     * CustomerAgeAttribute constructor.
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
     */
    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
    }


    public static function getDependencies()
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases()
    {
        return [];
    }


    public function apply()
    {
        $this->moduleDataSetup->startSetup();

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('quote_address'),
            'example',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment'  => 'Example',
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getTable('sales_order_address'),
            'example',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'length' => 255,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment'  => 'Example',
            ]
        );

        $this->moduleDataSetup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Note for this schema script, `'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT`, varchar is deprecated. If you specify type TYPE_TEXT but set length to lets say 255. Magento will create a MySQL column of VARCHAR type. [Add varchar column to order address](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9642/add-varchar-column-to-order-address).

Answer (score 0):

create a new file only with the modifications in quote_address and sales_order_address
example: https://github.com/experius/Magento-2-Module-Experius-ExtraCheckoutAddressFieldsTest/blob/master/Setup/InstallSchema.php